# My ethernet device has strange name on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ethernet

My ethernet device has strange name on Ubuntu, is this normal?

```
$ uname -a
Linux calculon 4.4.0-93-generic #116-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 11 21:17:51 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ ifconfig
enp0s31f6 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ...

~$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1c:1b:0d:ce:a7:84 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

$ lspci | egrep -i --color 'network|ethernet'
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
```

Comment: `ln -s /dev/null /etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-name-slot.rules` and a reboot should "solve" it. Otherwise, get used to it.

Comment: It's a `systemd` feature, apparently: https://askubuntu.com/questions/704361/why-is-my-network-interface-named-enp0s25-instead-of-eth0

Comment: To get your `eth0` back use the kernel option `net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0` (see this [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/741210/disabling-predictable-network-interface-names-in-xubuntu-15-10) ). The  `ln -s /dev/null /etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-name-slot.rules` didn't work for me in Debian 10 (Buster)